# Should I write "considered" or "considered as" in the following example?

Tags: word-usage

Example:

> He was very plain. He could be considered (as) the standard of the average.

Do I need the "as" in the following sentence? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Consider* in this sense takes three sorts of complements:

- `BARE {Noun/Adjective}:     I consider him {honest/an honest man}.`
- `INFINITIVAL:               I consider him to be {honest/an honest man}.`
- `'AS' PREPOSITION PHRASE:   I consider him as {honest/an honest man}.`

All three have been in common use for centuries and all three have the same meaning.

HOWEVER—
I recommend that you avoid the construction with *as*, because this may be understood to mean that you intend to 'consider' him in a particular aspect: you intend to discuss his honesty as opposed to, for instance, his competence or his opinions.

And I frankly see no positive reason for employing the infinitival construction; it adds nothing but a couple of empty syllables.

Comment: The _as_ construction, in this sentence, also invites the interpretation that the subject is among the candidates for the position of "standard of the average".